# Text input controller

Tags: html, function, controller

I need help on making an controler, that lets only int values to the text areas. my inputs that need the controller are:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="left">
Haigusjuhu kood:
<input type="text" name="doctor" id="historyId" onchange="" value="" class="txt_left" style="width:140px;" />
</td>
<td align="left">
 Dokumendi Id:
<input type="text" name="doctor" id="entryId" onchange="" value="" class="txt_left" style="width:140px;" />
</td>
<td align="left">
Patsient:
<input type="text" name="doctor" id="patientName" onchange="patientChange()" value="" class="txt_left" style="width:152px;" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

(The "Patsient" part isnt int so it doesnt need a controller, but the "Haigusjuhu kood" and "Dokumendi Id" need one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use JavaScript or JQuery 
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No worries :) keep moving.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you need to support old browsers, you can simply change your patient input to have a `type` of "number" instead of "text":

```
<input type="number" ... />
```

Users can still input non-numeric characters into the field, but they will not appear in the element's `value`.